# Questions about Python3 timedate module

Tags: python-3.x, timedelta

I have a quick question about a little snippet of code I've written and I have run into a little problem.

I have created a program I want to run for exactly one hour, then exit it self.

This does not seem to work as I saw it run for about three hours on my server the other day.

The variable I used to check if one hour had passed was declared this way:

```
timeLeft = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

and my check using and if/else statment this way:

```
if timeLeft > datetime.timedelta(hours=1.01):
   import myModule
   return myModule.exitMain()
else:
     return myProgMain
```

is the datetime.timedelta() function a valid check to see if an hour has passed or not?
or should I use time.time(3600) ?

Comment: you have to use while not if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop like this.

```
import time

seconds_to_run = 3600

start = time.time()
end = start + seconds_to_run

while time.time() < end:
    # call you code here
    print("hello")
    
print("Done")
```

You will repeatedly call your code for duration you mention and after it stops.

If you want to check based on timedelta,

```
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    elapsed = time_now - start
    
    if elapsed > datetime.timedelta(hours=1):
        print("Completed 1 hr")
        break
    
    # call your code here
    print("hi")
```